# Memory allocation of fixed size array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following tree node struct that holds pointers to other tree nodes:

```
struct node {
    // ...
    struct node* children[20];
}
```

The idea is that I want to check whether there is `node*` inside the `children` and based and that go deeper into the tree. So when I allocate the `node` I want to have `children` with 20 `NULL` values.
Currently I am not doin

1. How should I allocate this array in order to not get errors like `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` (Valgrind)?
2. Would it be better to use `struct node** children` and allocate fixed size each time I allocate a new node?

**EDIT:** Example of one place where Valgrind complains:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  if(node->children[i] != NULL)
    do_something_with_the_node(node->children[i]);
```

Comment: If you allocate the structure dynamically, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. Or use `memset` to set all contents to zero.

Comment: `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` reported by valgrind means that you have an `if` statement, in which you're comparing `node[x]`, right? Can you post that code too?

Comment: @g.tsh Yes. I've added an example.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, you can't portably use `calloc()` to set pointers to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate a new instance of `struct node`, you must set the contained pointers to `NULL` to mark them as "not pointing anywhere". This will make the Valgrind warning go away, since the pointers will no longer be uninitialized.

Something like this:

```
struct node * node_new(void)
{
  struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
  if(n != NULL)
  {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof n->children / sizeof *n->children; ++i)
      n->children[i] = NULL;
  }
  return n;
}
```

You *cannot* portably use either `memset()` on `n->children` **nor** `calloc()`, since those will give you "all bits zero" which is not the same as "pointer `NULL`".

Comment: Thanks, one more question: what is the difference between `memset()`/`calloc()` and setting pointer to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Your struct definition is valid (although it's hard to tell without more context if it fits your requirements).

Valgrind doesn't complain about your struct definition, it probably complains about how you instantiate variables of that type. Ensure that all of the array members get initialized and the complaints will most likely go away.

Comment: Currently I don't use {c,m} alloc to allocate the memory for this array (as I understand, I don't have to in this context). What I do later though is something like: `node->chlidren[10] = some_node_pointer;` (where values at other indices may stay uninitialized).

Comment: which is what valgrind complains about. In your example you added, you call `do_something_with_the_node()` depending on whether it's `NULL` or something else. You seem to expect the array members would be initialized to `NULL` automatically when they aren't. You need to explicitely initialize the whole array to `NULL` (using `memset()` or `calloc()`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an unintialized value in an `if` condition.

When you instantiate a `struct node`, its member `struct node* children[20];` is an array of 20 `struct node *`, all of which are uninitialized.

It would be no different from this:

```
char *x;

if (x == NULL) {
    /* Stuff */
}
```

At this point, `x` may have literally any value. In your example, any element of an array may have any value.

To fix this, you need to initialize the elements of an array before using them, for example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    node->children[i] = NULL;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
memset(node->children, 0, 20);
```

If you changed the member to, as you've suggested, `node **children`, the situation wouldn't be much different - you'll still need to initialize all the members, including array's elements. You could make it shorter by using `calloc`, which will initialize all bytes to `0`; then again, you'll need some code for correct deallocation (and remember to do it), so I think the tradeoff's not worth it.

Comment: Oh. IDK. Perhaps it's the issue mentioned by @unwind - that setting all zeroes instead of explicit `NULL` is not portable.